# If I brick my BIOS during update, can I use my computer if it was originally using UEFI?

Tags: boot, bios, hardware-failure, uefi, firmware

So my question basically is, if my BIOS needs an update and power goes out during flashing the update, can I still use my computer if it was originally using UEFI environment to boot the computer?

I know UEFI is independent from BIOS, that's why I ask this question. I want to know if UEFI in any way relies on BIOS firmware and want to know what happens to UEFI when the BIOS firmware bricks and loses its settings. Does my computer still boot with UEFI enabled if BIOS is out of work?

Comment: BIOS and UEFI are not the same, correct, but you either have BIOS or UEFI. It depends on your motherboard how bad it is going to be if the update fails. In most systems nowadays, the flashing has protection to restore to a default in case of such event, but not every motherboard has this.

Comment: If you brick a motherboard without a BIOS flashback feature, then you have bricked your motherboard.  Don't let the name fool you a "BIOS Flashback" feature would apply to a board with UEFI or BIOS.

Comment: CSM is a BIOS emulation mode within a UEFI system. It is still a UEFI system, but to the operating system it just looks like a BIOS system because all the firmware interfaces shown to it are the "old style" BIOS. The stuff "under the hood" is still UEFI. User1686 has the long and short of it in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, being independent doesn't mean a computer has both of them simultaneously. There's just one kind in any system, and it might use the UEFI architecture or it might not.

The term "BIOS" means two different things – it can refer *specifically* to the old "IBM PC BIOS" firmware type that's not UEFI, but it can also refer PC firmware *in general* regardless of type, and you'll often see people using it both ways. Even the firmware manufacturers themselves do this on occasion, with labels like "UEFI BIOS".

So if your computer has UEFI-compliant firmware and you do a "BIOS update", that really means you're just updating the system firmware in general, and in this case that's the same UEFI firmware that was being updated – *not* a completely independent thing.

(UEFI firmwares often have a mode to *emulate* the older BIOS architecture for old operating systems which require it, but that still doesn't mean you actually have both, it's still just one firmware that knows how to provide two different kinds of interfaces to an OS.)

Comment: Oh I see! So, the firmware that I already have installed on my motherboard is a UEFI and has the ability to switch to the legacy BIOS emulation-wise. So, there are no separate UEFI and BIOS firmware installed on newer motherboards then. It is just confusing because manufacturers use UEFI and BIOS terms interchangeably, but as a matter of fact it's UEFI for newer motherboards then, right?